# Unclear on how a sieve function is being generalized into a function that uses the möbius function

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, sieve-theory, mobius-function

I am reading through an AMS.org [article](http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1996-65-213/S0025-5718-96-00674-6/S0025-5718-96-00674-6.pdf) on prime counting.

- Let $\Phi(x,b)$ be the number of integers $i$ where $1 \le i \le x$ and $\gcd(i,p_b\#)=1$ where $p_b$ is the $b$th prime and $p_b\#$ is the [primorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primorial) for $p_b$
- Let $\Phi(x,0) = x$

Based on these two definitions, $\Phi(x,b)$ has the following two properties:

- $\Phi(u,0) = \left\lfloor{u}\right\rfloor$
- $\Phi(x,b) = \Phi(x,b-1) - \Phi(\frac{x}{p_b},b-1)$

I am clear on how these properties derive from the definitions.

The part that I am not clear on is the generalization to the following form:

$$\Phi(x,b) = \sum_{1 \le n \le x \text{ and } p^+(n) \le y }\mu(n)\left\lfloor\frac{x}{n}\right\rfloor$$

where $\mu(n)$ is the [möbius function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_function) and $p^+(n)$ is the greatest prime factor of $n$.

Here are my questions:

- I am not clear where $y$ is coming in or why $p^+(n)$ is being used.
- I am not clear how the two equations above generalize to the möbius function.
- I am not clear why the equation with the möbius function works.

If someone knows a reference that explains this in more detail, that would be very helpful.

---

Edit: I've made some progress based on the answer to this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1585340/48606).

Since $\left\lfloor\frac{\left\lfloor\frac{a}{b}\right\rfloor}{c}\right\rfloor = \left\lfloor\frac{a}{bc}\right\rfloor$, I am now clear on how the möbius function fits in.

I am still not clear on where $y$ is arbitrarily chosen between $x^{\frac{1}{3}}$ and $x^{\frac{1}{2}}$.

I am now clear on $p^+(n) \le y$ since if $p^+(n) > y$, it follows that there is another prime less than $y$.  So, we are doing this to avoid double counting these integers.

Comment: Are you sure the second property you write is correct? In any case, $y$ is not clear what should represent. By the way, from your definition of $\Phi(x,b)$, it seems to count the number of integers up to $x$ non-divisible by the first $b$ primes, that is the number of primes up to $x$ excluded the first $b$. In other words, shouldn't be $\Phi(x,b)=\pi(x)-b$?

Comment: Thanks for your questions.  $y$ is referenced earlier in the article as a value between $x^{1/3}$ and $x^{1/2}$ but I don't see how it relates or how it is being used in the general equation.  I'm not clear on your question about $\Phi(x,b)$.  It is counting the number of integers with a least prime factor greater than $p_b$ so $\Phi(x)=\pi(x)-b$ won't work.

Comment: Maybe I got confused, but if you say that $\gcd(i,p_b\#)=1$ it means that the integer $i$ is not divisible by any of the first $b$ primes, so it should be factorized as product of powers of primes greater than $p_b$, or not?

Comment: You got it.  :-)  It should be factored as a product of powers of primes greater than $p_b$.

Comment: Btw, I gave a quick look at your paper, $y$ is defined as an integer between $x^{1/3}$ and $x^{1/2}$, together with $b=\pi(y)$. The formula involving the Moebius function should arise from iterating the second property you wrote, look at the picture at the end of page 3 in the paper.

Comment: Thanks.  That's one of the answers that I was looking for when I wrote the question.  :-)  Are you clear on why $y$ can be arbitrarily chosen in that range rather than setting $y= x^{\frac{1}{2}}$?

Comment: Sorry I just gave a quick look at the paper, no idea!