Induction proof for floor function composition
Given the following function:
$$P(x)=\left\lfloor\frac{x}{2}\right\rfloor$$
I want to prove the following simplification:
$$\underbrace{P(P(\cdots P(x)\cdots))}_{l \text{ times}}=\left\lfloor\frac{x}{2^l}\right\rfloor$$
By induction, the base case is stated and verified as follows:
$$P(x)=\left\lfloor\frac{x}{2^1}\right\rfloor$$
However, what floor function property can be used to show the following?
$$\underbrace{P(P(\cdots P(x)\cdots))}_{l+1 \text{ times}}=\left\lfloor\frac{x}{2^{l+1}}\right\rfloor$$

Use \left \lfloor and \right\rfloor to wrap around with the floor function with MathJax. e.g. \left \lfloor \frac{x}{2^l} \right \rfloor

Well this is more interesting than your other floor function question from earlier today, but I think you can still use similar ideas to prove it. You don't need induction.

@adam-rubinson If $x$ were always even the equality is easy to prove. However, the odd case entangles the procedure.

It might help to think in terms of the binary representation of integers. $P(x)$ is the number which is obtained by removing the least significant binary digit from $x$.

I'll buck the trend and say induction (although unnecessary [and even a crutch]) is much easier.  DOn't have to worry about negative numbers or non decimals...

Hmm.... actually even if we do $P(x)$ is the number obtained by removing the least significant binary digit, that's only one step.  You still have to use "induction thinking" to get that doing it repetitively is removing the least $l$ digits.

@MartinR I changed the [tag:analysis] tag to [tag:real-analysis] due to its description ("Consider a more specific tag (...)").

I'll assume throughout that $x\geq 0$ (although I'm not sure this assumption is necessary).
Lemma $1$:$\quad l,n\in\mathbb{N},\ x\geq 2^l n \implies P^l(x)\geq n.$ This is Statement $Q(l).$
Proof (induction on $l$): Basis case ($l=1):\ x\geq 2^1 n = 2n \implies \frac{x}{2} \geq n \implies \displaystyle \left \lfloor \frac{x}{2} \right\rfloor \geq n,$ because $n\in\mathbb{N}.$ Induction step: Suppose Statement $Q(l)$ is true, and suppose $x\geq 2^{l+1} n = 2^l (2n).$ From the supposition, it follows that $P^l(x)\geq 2n,\implies\ \frac{P^l(x)}{2} \geq n\in\mathbb{N} \implies P^{l+1}(x)= \displaystyle\left \lfloor \frac{P^l(x)}{2} \right\rfloor \geq n,$ because $n\in\mathbb{N}.$
Lemma $2$:$\quad l,n\in\mathbb{N},\ 0\leq x < 2^l n \implies P^l(x)< n.\ $ This is Statement $S(n).$
Proof (induction on $l$): Basis case ($l=1):\ x<2n \implies \frac{x}{2} < n\in\mathbb{N} \implies \displaystyle \left \lfloor \frac{x}{2} \right\rfloor \leq n-1< n.$ Induction step: Suppose Statement $S(l)$ is true, and suppose $x < 2^{l+1} n = 2^l (2n).$ From the supposition, it follows that $P^l(x) < 2n,\implies\ \frac{P^l(x)}{2} < n\in\mathbb{N} \implies P^{l+1}(x)= \displaystyle\left \lfloor \frac{P^l(x)}{2} \right\rfloor \leq n-1 < n,$ because $n\in\mathbb{N}.$

Theorem: For any $l\in\mathbb{N},\ P^l(x)=\displaystyle\left\lfloor\frac{x}{2^l}\right\rfloor.$
Proof: $\exists\ k\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$ such that $ k2^l \leq x < (k+1)2^l.$ Lemma $1\implies P^l(x)\geq k;\ $ Lemma $2\implies P^l(x) < k+1.$ Thus, $k\leq P^l(x) < k+1.$ But $P^l(x)\in\mathbb{Z},$ and so $P^l(x)=k.$ On the other hand, since $ k2^l \leq x < (k+1)2^l,$ it follows that $ k \leq \frac{x}{2^l} < (k+1),\implies \displaystyle\left\lfloor\frac{x}{2^l}\right\rfloor=k$ also.

I have left out some details like $n$ being a non-positive integer. But I have left it to the reader to fill in the gaps.

Thanks for the answer.

Let
$$
 x = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n 2^n + R
$$
where $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n 2^n$ is the base-$2$ representation of the integral part of $x$, and $0 \le R < 1$ is the fractional part of $x$. Here all $a_n$ are $0$ or $1$, and only finitely many of them are non-zero.
Then
$$
 P(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_{n+1} 2^n
$$
and by induction it follows that
$$
\underbrace{P(P(\cdots P(x)\cdots))}_{l \text{ times}} =
\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_{n+l} 2^n \, .
$$
On the other hand,
$$
\left\lfloor\frac{x}{2^l}\right\rfloor
= \left\lfloor \frac{1}{2^l}\left(\sum_{n=0}^{l-1} a_n 2^{n} + R \right) + \sum_{n=l}^{\infty} a_n 2^{n-l}\right\rfloor
= \sum_{n=l}^{\infty} a_n 2^{n-l} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_{n+l} 2^n
$$
because $0 \le \frac{1}{2^l}\left(\sum_{n=0}^{l-1} a_n 2^{n} + R \right)< 1$ and $\sum_{n=l}^{\infty} a_n 2^{n-l}$ is an integer.

My advice is not to focus so much on powers of $2$ and instead prove this theorem by proving a more general theorem.
Theorem.  For $x \in \mathbf R$ and positive integers $m$ and $n$,
$$
\left\lfloor  \frac{\lfloor x/n \rfloor}{m}\right\rfloor = \left\lfloor \frac{x}{mn}\right\rfloor.
$$
Your result is an immediate consequence of this theorem: writing $P^j$ for the $j$-fold iterate of $P$, if $P^{l}(x) = \lfloor x/2^l \rfloor$ for all $x$, then $P^{l+1}(x) = P(P^l(x)) = \lfloor P^l(x)/2\rfloor = \lfloor \lfloor x/2^l\rfloor /2\rfloor = \lfloor x/(2^l2)\rfloor = \lfloor x/2^{l+1}\rfloor$.
The proof of this theorem is short, bypassing binary expansions and various case distinctions I see in other posted answers. Here it is.
Proof.  Let $N = \lfloor x/(mn)\rfloor$.  Then $N \leq x/(mn) < N+1$< so $Nm \leq x/n < Nm + m$, so $\lfloor x/n\rfloor = Nm + r$ for some integer $r$ such that $0 \leq r < m$. Thus $\lfloor x/n\rfloor/m = N + r/m$, with $0 \leq r/m < 1$. Thus $\lfloor \lfloor x/n\rfloor/m\rfloor = N = \lfloor x/(mn)\rfloor$.  QED
I did not have this theorem available in my memory to recall when I saw your question. Instead, what I did know already is that $\lfloor x/n\rfloor = \lfloor \lfloor x\rfloor/n\rfloor$. Since $2^{l+1} = 2^l2$, I guessed the theorem I already knew ought to have some extension to a more general theorem that has yours as a special case. The theorem I wrote above was the first idea that came to me, and it worked. I am a bit surprised all other answers focus on the binary case.

Indeed, and with that insight the question becomes a duplicate: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1585340/42969

@MartinR I see my proof here matches the proof by
JimmyK4542 there.

If $P(P(...P(x)...))=P_n(x)$ your aim is to prove (in the induction step) that:
$$P_{n+1}(x)=P(P_n(x))$$
or:
$$\left\lfloor{\frac{x}{2^{n+1}}}\right\rfloor=\left\lfloor{\frac{\left\lfloor{\frac{x}{2^{n}}}\right\rfloor}{2}}\right\rfloor\tag{1}$$
Assume that:
$$\left\lfloor{\frac{x}{2^{n}}}\right\rfloor=q\tag{2}$$
It means that:
$$q\cdot 2^n\le x \lt(q+1)\cdot2^n$$
$$q\le \frac{x}{2^n} \lt q+1$$
$$\frac q2\le \frac{x}{2^{n+1}} \lt \frac{q+1}2\tag{3}$$
This means that:
If $q=2k$:
$$k\le \frac{x}{2^{n+1}} \lt \frac{2k+1}2=k+\frac12\implies \left\lfloor{\frac{x}{2^{n+1}}}\right\rfloor=k=\frac q2=\left\lfloor{\frac q2}\right\rfloor\tag{4}$$
If $q=2k+1$:
$$k+\frac 12\le \frac{x}{2^{n+1}} \lt k+1= \implies \left\lfloor{\frac{x}{2^{n+1}}}\right\rfloor=k=\left\lfloor{\frac q2}\right\rfloor\tag{5}$$
So in both cases we have:
$$\implies \left\lfloor{\frac{x}{2^{n+1}}}\right\rfloor=\left\lfloor{\frac q2}\right\rfloor\tag{6}$$
Replace (2) into (6) and the statement (1) is proved.

The first sentence is weird: if $P(P(...P(x)...))=P_n(x)$, then by definition it means that $P_{n+1}(x) = P(P_n(x))$ so we cannot aim to prove this. Did you mean that the aim is to prove $P_{n+1}(x) = \left\lfloor \frac{x}{2^{n+1}} \right\rfloor$ given that $P_n(x) = \left\lfloor \frac{x}{2^n} \right\rfloor$?

Suppose that $P^{(\ell)}(x)=\lfloor x/2^\ell\rfloor$. Then $P^{(\ell+1)}(x)=\lfloor \lfloor x/2^\ell\rfloor/2\rfloor$. Let $k\in\{0,1,2,...\}$. Note that if $x\in[k2^{\ell },(k+1)2^{\ell})$ then $\lfloor x/2^\ell\rfloor=k$ so $\lfloor x/2^\ell\rfloor/2=k/2$. For all $k$ even we have $P^{(\ell+1)}(x)=k/2$. On the other hand, for each $k$ odd we have $P^{(\ell+1)}(x) =(k-1)/2$.
Let $n\in\{0,1,2,...\}$. For $x\in[n2^{\ell+1},(n+1)2^{\ell+1})=[(2n)2^{\ell},(2n+2)2^{\ell})$ we have
$$P^{(\ell+1)}(x)=
\begin{cases}
\frac{2n}{2}=n&x\in [(2n)2^{\ell},(2n+1)2^{\ell})\\
\frac{(2n+1)-1}{2}=n&x\in [(2n+1)2^{\ell},(2n+2)2^{\ell})
\end{cases}$$
We conclude: for $x\in[n2^{\ell+1},(n+1)2^{\ell+1})$
$$P^{(\ell+1)}(x)=n=\lfloor\frac{x}{2^{\ell+1}}\rfloor$$

Notation: $P^n(x)$ means the $n$-fold composition of $P$ applied to $x$, i.e. $\underbrace{P(\ldots P(x)\ldots)}_{n \text{ times}}$.
Let $x = k \cdot 2^l + r$ with $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $0 \leqslant r < 2^l$. Then:

$\frac{x}{2} = k \cdot 2^{l-1} + \frac{r}{2}$ and $0 \leqslant \frac{r}{2} < 2^{l-1}$, so $P(x) = k \cdot 2^{l-1} + r_1$ for some $0 \leqslant r_1 < 2^{l-1}$.
$\frac{P(x)}{2} = k \cdot 2^{l-2} + \frac{r_1}{2}$ and $0 \leqslant \frac{r_1}{2} < 2^{l-2}$, so $P^2(x) = k \cdot 2^{l-2} + r_2$ for some $0 \leqslant r_2 < 2^{l-2}$.
etc.

Repeating this $l$ times, we get $P^l(x) = k + r_l$ for some $0 \leqslant r_l < 1$, hence just $P^l(x) = k$ because $P^l(x)$ is an integer. On the other hand, $\left\lfloor \frac{x}{2^l} \right\rfloor = k$ as well. Therefore
$$P^l(x) = \left\lfloor \frac{x}{2^l} \right\rfloor.$$

Note that $[\frac x{2^l}]=m;m\in \mathbb Z \iff m \le \frac x{2^l} < (m+1)\iff m2^l \le x < (m+1)2^l$.
And suppose we know, as induction hypotheses that $\underbrace {P(P....(x))}_l = [\frac {x}{2^l}] = m$ while $m2^l \le x < (m+1)2^l$.
What next?
Now if $m=2k$ is even then $m2^l=k2^{l+1} \le x < (m+1)2^l=(2k+1)2^l < (m+2)2^l=(k+1)2^{l+1}$.
So $\underbrace {P(P....(x))}_{l+1}=[\frac m2]=[\frac {2k}2] = k$. While $[\frac x{2^{l+1}}]= k$.  So $\underbrace {P(P....(x))}_{l+1}=[\frac x{2^l}]$
And if $m=2k+1$ is odd then $2k2^{l}=k2^{l+1} < (2k+1)2^{l}=m2^{l} \le x < (k+1)2^{l+1}=(2k+2)2^{l}=(m+1)2^{l}$
So $\underbrace {P(P....(x))}_{l+1}=[\frac m2]=[\frac {2k+1}2] = k$. While  $[\frac x{2^{l+1}}] = k$. So $\underbrace {P(P....(x))}_{l+1}=[\frac x{2^l}]$
And that's our induction step proven.
